# Subspace of infinite dimensional complex projective space generated by compact set

Tags: complex-geometry

This question is similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/941897) one, but with the infinite dimensional complex space instead of the complex separable Hilbert space.

My question is: if $S\subseteq \mathbb C P^\infty $ is a compact subset, then is it true that the projective subspace generated by $S$ is finite dimensional?

The counterexample in the linked question clearly fails in this modified case.

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you mean by the "projective subspace generated by $S$"?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no!

**Example:** Similarly to [Hilbert cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube) in $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$, let $H=\{0\}\times[0,1]\times\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\times\dots$ it is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$, therefore $\pi(H\setminus\{\underline{0}\})=K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{P}^{\infty}_{\mathbb{C}}$, where $\pi:\mathbb{C}^{\infty}\setminus\{\underline{0}\}\to\mathbb{P}^{\infty}_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the canonical projection; but the projective (linear) space generated by $K$ is the hyperlane $\{x_0=0\}$, where $x_0$ is the first coordinate in $\mathbb{P}^{\infty}_{\mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: Your subset $H$ contains zero, which is not in the domain of $\pi$. Perhaps you meant to make the first coordinate equal to $1$?

Comment: Yes it is, $\underline{0}\in H$; I remark that $H\setminus\{\underline{0}\}=K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}\setminus\{0\}$, so $\pi(K)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{P}^{\infty}_{\mathbb{C}}$ and it generates $\{x_0=0\}$. Are you agree?