# Compact normed linear space

Tags: normed-spaces

Does there exist a compact normed linear space?

All I can see is that if there is any it must be finite-dimensional. But does there exist any other than the trivial one i.e. $(0)$?

Comment: Is the real line or the complex line compact?

Comment: No @kimchilover..............

Comment: There you are, then: if there is a non-zero element of your space, it contains a copy of the scalar multiples of that element.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941897/examples-of-compact-sets-that-are-infinite-dimensional-and-not-bounded